# Access the clustered web console

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis in a master / slave cluster with HA. I access it through the host of each master, but through the VIP that delivers the hosts, he keeps asking me to login in loop.

Here is an image of the topology that is currently working.

[image]

Only the access to the console by the VIP does not work. I use the same topology for ActiveMQ and it works. I am balanced for the master host.
Is it possible to access the ActiveMQ Artemis web console through a single point?

Comment: Are all these brokers in a cluster together?

Comment: On different servers.
However, as shown in the topology, they are in different zones, but they talk to each other.

Comment: I mean from the perspective ActiveMQ Artemis are they in a cluster? For example, did you configure a `cluster-connection` for them so that they all can share messages, etc.?

Comment: Yes, and the cluster and HA function is working and I see messages being shared between them. 
The only thing I don't see working is to access the web console via vip and see the messages on a master for example host-1 and after the refresh see the messages on host-3, master too. 
Every time I authenticate I am redirected to login again.

Comment: The configuration below is as follows:
<connectors>
<connector name = "netty-connector"> tcp://host-1:61616 </connector>
<connector name = "host-3"> tcp://host-3:61616 </connector>
<connector name = "host-4"> tcp://host-4:61616 </connector>
</connectors>

Comment: <ha-policy>
    <shared-store>
        <master>
          <failover-on-shutdown> true </failover-on-shutdown>
        </master>
    </shared-store>
</ha-policy>

Comment: <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection-uri address="static://(tcp://host-3:61616, tcp://host-4:61616)? connectorName=netty-connector;retryInterval=500;messageLoadBalancingType= ON_DEMAND; maxHops=1" name="my-cluster"/>
</cluster-connections>

Comment: @IgorMagalhães Facing the same issue. Were you able to solve the issue?